# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')

Tags: vue.js

```html
<div class="button" @click="shows = !show">
  <i class="fas fa-plus-circle" v-if="show"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-minus-circle" v-else></i>
</div>
```

If I click the element it shows the error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')".

Not sure why but there seems to be issues when rendering  elements when inside the element attached with the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

This `@click="shows = !show"` is not correct code. You should declare a function in `methods` section:

```js
methods: {
 onClick() {
   this.show = !this.show;
 }
}
```

And then use it:

```js
@click="onClick"
```

Also, maybe this is a typo? `show**s** = !show`

Comment: Figured it out. using dom.watch() in Fontawesome in vue js so it was converting <i> to <svg>. just encapsulate  <i> with <div> and add the v-if and v-else on <div>. Now its working.

Comment: For me comment above didnt work
Fix just like full re-render:

    <button v-if="isShowTrackList" @click="iconClickShowListHandler">
      <i class="fas fa-bars fa-rotate-90"></i>
    </button>
    <button v-else @click="iconClickShowListHandler">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>